# Can you use Open Image Denoise on the GPU in Blender 2.91? In Blender, Will it Only Work on the CPU?

Tags: gpu, denoise

Can you use Open Image Denoise on the GPU in blender 2.91 or will it only work on the CPU? And if you can do it on the GPU, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like it is made for CPUs: https://www.openimagedenoise.org/ so it does not work on GPUs. It's created by a CPU manufacturer after all. We have OptiX denoiser for GPUs.